# Is it possible to use two head and two body tags on the same page?

Tags: html

I want to be able to upload a file and while the file is being transferred have something like a progress bar giving feedback to the user. 
When the server start to receive the file it will immediately start to output html and when the file has finished to upload the server starts to output the real page.

The thing is that I don't know what is going in the head until the file is uploaded. So my question is if I can use two html tags and two body tags without breaking the page, even if it's a really fugly solution, and what are the consequences.

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't even think that way, you will make google angry :)

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot. This doesn't [w3-validate](http://validator.w3.org/) and the behaviour among browsers is unspecified and not guaranteed to be consistent.

I strongly recommend to show the result in an `<iframe>` instead.